# Do I know my GRE scores when I choose to send them on test day?

Tags: gre

I haven't started preparing for the GRE and I have my exam in a week's time (15th Oct.). I know I'll get a low score which is why I don't want to report the score to any university. So, I have two options:

1. Reschedule the exam to something like 10th Nov.
2. Take the exam on 15th Oct. and take it again after 21 days.

I will go with option two if reporting the scores is optional after taking the exams since reporting the score is my only fear in regard to my question.

Do I have to report my score when I take the GRE? Do I know my scores before I choose?

Comment: Have you tried googling to see what the GRE's policy on score reporting is?

Comment: Hi Ronak, welcome to Academia.SE. I tried to edit your question to make it a bit more generalizable. Let me know if I changed your question too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finish the GRE, at least a computer-delivered GRE, you will be asked if you want to report  or cancel your scores. If you choose "cancel," you don't get to see them or report them. If you choose "report," you get your unofficial scores, then are asked to report them.

According to [ETS](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/send/) (emphasis added):

> On test day, **after** completing the test and viewing your unofficial Verbal Reasoning and Quantitative Reasoning scores, you will be asked to designate which score recipients you want to receive your General Test scores.

At this point, **reporting is optional**, you don't have to report to anyone at this point.

---

As for whether *you personally* should reschedule or retake it after 21 days, that's a question we can't answer, but hopefully this information helps you decide.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination! It answered all my queries!

Comment: @RonakSharma if that answer was the most helpful to you, then you should accept it using the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question - yes, you will be prompted after you have finished your GRE to decide whether or not you wish to see your score. If you select "yes," you are provided scores on your verbal and quantitative reasoning, but not the analytical writing section (which must be graded). The full score sheet becomes available to you within a few weeks of taking the test. If you decide to take the test twice, it is possible that your first test's scores will come in by the time you are eligible to take the GRE again, which would allow you to reflect on the areas you need to work on the hardest.

Regarding your two options - this is completely up to you and a personal decision since you know your own academic capabilities and strengths far better than we do, but something to consider - depending on your field and program, taking it twice (despite the pain to your wallet) doesn't hurt. I have found that many people, like myself, performed far better the second time taking the test, whether they studied more or less. Taking it this first time could allow you to get comfortable with the testing facility and test structure/format, and then you could take it a second time with more preparation. I studied extremely hard for a year prior to taking my first GRE. The second time, I did not have much time to review, but I felt far more comfortable because I had nothing to lose (especially thanks to Score Select). I ended up scoring several quartiles higher in the verbal reasoning category and even exceeding the recommended score that institutions had suggested for my program.

Others might say to hold off, which is also valid because the GRE is testing you on your ability to work methodologically through their questions in a manner that, realistically, requires some practice, even for the best and brightest test takers. The free Kaplan practice test helped me assess my strengths and weaknesses, but despite how much my study resources helped in the long run, neither practice tests nor all of my studying could have prepared me for how the test was structured in the actual testing facility, except for just going ahead and taking it.

Regardless of your choice, keep graduate coordinators or any other relevant parties in the loop, if the timing of your tests is something that they need to be told about. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sharing your experience. I'll definitely keep that in mind before taking any decision.